# Is it possible to specify newline type while reading a file in ruby

Tags: ruby, character-encoding

I frequently deal with UTF-16LE files encoded on windows which have a \r\n carriage return.  There is no problem converting the file to UTF-8 by using:

```
File.new(filepath, 'r:utf-16le:utf-8')
```

But this of course does not get rid of the \r.  The way I currently get rid of them is with

```
str.gsub("\r", "")
```

But it would be nice to take care of it while reading the file in.  String#encode has :cr_newline, :crlf_newline, and :universal_newline options which convert all newlines to a desired kind of newline.  Is there a way to apply these or similar options while reading in a file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method IO#gets takes an optional argument that allows you to pass a string to define how to separate the lines:

```
file = File.new(filepath, 'r:utf-16le:utf-8')
while (line = file.gets("\r\n"))
   ...
end
```

Comment: Thanks alien, this is just what I was looking for.  It would be nice if there were a way to integrate it into the creation of the file object, but this solution still saves me the gsub code.

Comment: If you really want, you could subclass File and override the method gets, but I don't think it's worth it.